# What scratch orgs to do?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

im new in salesforce.I have a question and hope you guys can explain for me.Im understading about scratch org is a container to make developer create a custom environment to develop his feature.But when i create a scratch org (i call it scratch org A) and then i write some codes and push them to scratch org A.Then i create another scratch org(i call it is scratch org B) and retrive source from orgs . i see list source retrive from org B have code in org A. So can you explain for me ? Thanks you so much.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. I'm having a hard time following your question. Could you add some concrete details, such as actual commands you run and the results you see?

Comment: When dealing with multiple orgs, it is easy to get mixed up about which org you are accessing, Running `sfdx force:org:display` will tell you which org your commands will target by default. Scratch orgs only contain source that you push or deploy into them.

Comment: @DavidReed thank you for replying . I did understand what i want.can you explain for me another question?i wanna know when i get data from a get query and then i execute update this data(datas not change), salesforce database engine that do execute update data? thanks for replaying and sorry about my english!! :3